# Align two sequence of points using linear regression

Tags: regression, matlab

I have two sets of points in 2D space, `S1={a1,a2,....,an}` and `S2={b1,b2,....,bn}`. I would like to align S2 such that `min(sum(|S2i – S1i.T|^2))` from `i=1 to n`. where **T** is a **2×2 matrix** for aligning the points of **S1i**, and **S2i** are the points for the target sequence.

I would like to achieve that using linear regression. Any idea how can estimate the matrix **T**. Matlab code could be very helpful also.

Comment: Apart from that, do you want matrix T to be a rotation matrix, or not necessarily?

Comment: @amoeba since the sequences S1 and S2  take varies directions, the rotation is required to align S2 into S1 with minimum error.

Comment: Still not clear: do you want to *constrain* T to be a rotation matrix (that's a special kind of 2x2 matrix) or do you want to find the best T whatever it will be?

Comment: @amoeba I need T whatever it (as 2x2 matrix).